AWS Log insights - finding logs with pattern in different lines
I am looking to query my lambda logs using logs insights by applying pattern which falls in different log lines.
My logs look like this:
START RequestID: 12345
event:{'id':1,'name':'abc'}
processed this request
END RequestID: 12345
START RequestID: 56789
event:{'id':2,'name':'xyz'}
failed to process
END RequestID: 56789

I would like to get the events that were processed successfully. Since the lines are different, I am not getting the result if I use @message like 'event:' and @message like 'processed this request'. Also, I am not able to use requestId because every line in my logs doesn't hold this value.
